# problem occurred while installing react app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, create-react-app

When I try to create new app using command

```
npx create-react-app
```

then it stuck in found 0 vulnerabilities as shown below. It doesn't move ahead after that.

```
Installing packages. This might take a couple of minutes.
Installing react, react-dom, and react-scripts with cra-template...


> core-js@2.6.11 postinstall E:\reactProject\sumit\node_modules\babel-runtime\node_modules\core-js
> node -e "try{require('./postinstall')}catch(e){}"


> core-js@3.6.5 postinstall E:\reactProject\sumit\node_modules\core-js
> node -e "try{require('./postinstall')}catch(e){}"


> core-js-pure@3.6.5 postinstall E:\reactProject\sumit\node_modules\core-js-pure
> node -e "try{require('./postinstall')}catch(e){}"

+ react-scripts@3.4.3
+ react-dom@16.13.1
+ cra-template@1.0.3
+ react@16.13.1
added 1585 packages from 745 contributors and audited 1589 packages in 143.456s

64 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details

found 0 vulnerabilities
```

How to fix it.

Comment: You issue looks familiar to [this](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/8441)

Comment: can i have package.json file ?